# Cannot install TWRP on Nexus 6 (Android 7 installed) via MacOS

Tags: android

### Purpose:

Install TWRP into Nexus 6 with Android 7 via macOS.
(I have tested in Windows, it works)

### Problem:

I have a nexus 6 device with Android 7 installed. 
I would like to install TWRP into Android 7, but I cannot copy TWRP to my nexus. The error message is the followings,

```
  $fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
  (bootloader) has-slot:recovery: not found
  target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
  sending 'recovery' (0 KB)...
  FAILED (remote failure)
  finished. total time: 0.000s
```

May I know how do I solve the issue?

### Environment and Steps

`macos EI Caption`, `Nexus 6 (Android 7)`, `twrp-3.0.2-0-shamu.img`

I performed the following commands,

```
$adb reboot bootloader
$fastboot flash recovery recovery.img 
// error here. 
// recovery.img which is twrp-3.0.2-0-shamu.img, just rename it.
```

I have googled, and someone said it's caused by locked OEM devices.
however, my device is unlocked.

Comment: run as root (on mac) or use sudo ?